# Matlab - determining branches in skeletons

Tags: matlab, image-processing

By using `bwmorph`, one can identify the branch points in a skeleton and by subtracting them from the skeleton image, the residual image is left with the different branches. However, configurations that one would intrepid as two different branches may be found as a single branch by this method.

Given the configuration

0X 
0X 
0BXX 
Y

Where B is the branch point and X and Y represents the starts of the branches (0 is just for alignment), our method gives us the two different branches X and Y. However, X splits in two different directions and might be natural to consider as two different branches.

Is there a good way to separate such cases into two different branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have identified the branch points, you can dilate them by 1 before subtracting. This also gets rid of single-pixel "branches".

Comment: Thank you. There is only one problem with dilating the branch points. In areas with many branch points one may want to use a single pixel definition of the branch point. Any suggestions for a decision rule of when to dilate the branch points?

Comment: @Mykje: I don't know your data, and there isn't a generic answer for this question. However, you may want to look into local density of points (k-nearest neighbor distance) to decide whether you dilate or not.